# Background color transition from white to blue with css

Tags: html, css

Sorry about my question, it could be that there is a solution/answer on my question. I am really beginner with CSS so I hope that can solve my imagination...what is:
I have a webpage with 3 columns. What I want: the background-color of the left column go from white to blue and the right column background-color go from blue to write...

Is is possible to use CSS for it or I have to create a "small" background image and repeat that...

Thanks for your answer and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do with css gradient property:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp